# make tcolorbox to fit text (height and depth)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox, highlighting

I use a tikz environment to create a box around some text small part of text (such as a [Stabilo Boss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwan-Stabilo#/media/File:Markeerstift-01_(xndr).jpg) highlighting). Using some tikz `height` and `depth` functions I manage to tight the box to the text size (see below). For some reason I would like to do the same with `tcolorbox` but I couldn't manage to get a proper alignment.

Is there a way to tell `tcolorbox` (I use last version, 3.94 at time of writing) to align all boxes' text to the baseline and fit their heights to text height+depth?

TIA.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{calc}


\newcommand{\thl}[2][]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline = (text.base)]%
    \node[%
      inner sep = 0pt,
      text depth = depth("Cap"),
      text height = height("Cap"),
      fill=yellow,
      %text depth={}, text height={},
  #1] (text) {#2};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}%


\begin{document}

With \texttt{tikz}:

inlined \thl{e}\thl[fill=red!20]{p}\thl[fill=green!20]{é}\thl[fill=blue!20]{b} text.


With \texttt{tcolorbox}:

\tcbset{tcbox raise base,nobeforeafter, on line, size=minimal}
minimal: 
inlined \tcbox[colback=yellow]{e}\tcbox[colback=red!20]{p}\tcbox[colback=green!20]{é}\tcbox[colback=blue!20]{b} text.

\tcbset{on line, size=tight}

tight:
inlined \tcbox[colback=yellow]{e}\tcbox[colback=red!20]{p}\tcbox[colback=green!20]{é}\tcbox[colback=blue!20]{b} text.

\tcbset{on line, size=minimal, height=\fontcharht\font`B+\fontchardp\font`q}
fixed height:
inlined \tcbox[colback=yellow]{e}\tcbox[colback=red!20]{p}\tcbox[colback=green!20]{é}\tcbox[colback=blue!20]{b} text.


\end{document}
```

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do this? TikZ is arguably a sledge-hammer to crack this nut (though probably not and I probably wouldn't care anyway), but `tcolorbox` is surely bringing in a steam roller. ;)  You can probably include a `\strut` or something into the box, but it really seems over the top to use a new `tcolorbox` for every character. (Or a new `tikzpicture` for each one, for that matter.) If you use this much, it will be slooowww.

Comment: @cfr Here the new `tcolorbox` was just for the example. I guess having a `strut` or something similar is the right way to do it. The only problem with the `strut` itself is that it's to to high. One can define the correct size with `rule`.

Comment: You could also use a `\phantom` combined with a box of zero width, probably, and put `Cap` in it. Or probably `tcolorbox` lets you specify the TeX keys just the same way you do for TikZ if you load the appropriate libraries. Depending on the options you choose, you can pretty much design your own TikZ box with it.

Comment: That's it thanks for the tricks. Actually `\vphantom{Cap}` does the job. Just another TIL ;-)

Comment: Glad you sorted it. No idea what TIL means. :-)

Comment: Today/Thing I Learned.

Comment: Aha! I was thinking TeX or Ti*k*Z for the `T` ;).